# How to fix FragmentManager is already executing transactions in FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a trouble in `FragmentManager is already executing transactions`. I research on how to solve this but the answers aren't the one I am having in my codes. They use viewpager and fragment manager but i am using a fragment transaction only because i am using a bottom navigation bar.

The root cause is the snapshot listener from the home fragment. Can someone help me to fix this? Here's my code:

```
MainActivity.java
final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String UserID = intent.getStringExtra("userid");

        final HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundleh = new Bundle();
        bundleh.putString("userid", UserID);
        fragment.setArguments(bundleh);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
```

And here is the line where the error was pointing

```
HomeFragment.java
db.collection("Baskets").document(uid).collection("Store_Baskets")
                .addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null){
                            Log.e(LOG_DB, e.toString());
                        }else {
                            List<String> ids = null;
                            for (DocumentSnapshot ds: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                ids.add(ds.getId());
                            }
                            if (ids.size()==0){
                                basket_count.setText("0");
                            }else {
                                basket_count.setText(String.valueOf(ids.size()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamakers.coonna/com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeBuyersActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2207)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2267)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:814)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.lambda$onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:180)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope$$Lambda$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5384)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.bind(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:192)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListenerInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:1035)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:995)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:939)
        at com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1244)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using firebase and you are listening for changes to document like this

```
     docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            //Doing work
        }
    });
```

update your code to use ListenerRegistration Instead

```
  ListenerRegistration registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        }
    });
```

and remove it once you are done

```
   @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    registration.remove();
}
```

Comment: also use getChildFragmentManager() when starting a fragment from another fragment.

Comment: Yes I am doing it but I am still getting an error even I used it. On getChildFragment() I cant use it because it cant resolve but when I add the fragment before the getChildFragmentManager() it solves it but I am having an arror again with Fragment has not been attached yet.

Comment: you should only call getChildFragmentManager when you are in another fragment. Have you also changed your code to use ListenerRegistration?

Answer (score 1):

You should move the db.collection related code from HomeFragment's `onCreate()` into `onActivityCreated()`, and use `getChildFragmentManager()` inside your fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
fragment.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also, you should use `fragmentTransaction.commit();` instead of `fragmentTransaction.commitNow();`

From the Javadoc:

> Transactions committed using `commitNow()` may not be added to the
>   FragmentManager's back stack
>
> A transaction can only be committed with `commitNow()` prior to its
>   containing activity saving its state.  If the commit is attempted
>   after that point, an exception will be thrown.  This is because the
>   state after the commit can be lost if the activity needs to be
>   restored from its state.

Comment: I just change it to `commit()` but my app still crashing

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: What is mPagerAdapter sir?

Comment: I'va updated my question and post the stacktrace sir. Please take a look.

Comment: Call fragment.getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I have a new error: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamakers.coonna/com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeBuyersActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.`

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308981/2068732

Comment: Still can't fix it sir. Cannot resolve ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: At oncreate sir

Comment: Your fragment is not attached to MainActivity but with HomeBuyersActivity

Comment: Home buyers activity is my mainactivity sir.

Comment: Can you move the code from  HomeFragment's onCreate() into onActivityCreated() ?